# Python+Sqlite3, how to update table using "index"

Tags: python, sqlite, indexing, where-clause, using

Error pops up while accessing database using index.

I think 'index' is not available in the sql query 'WHERE index =?'

How can I update database by using index column?

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "index": syntax error
```

```html
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3


# Create DB file
con = sqlite3.connect("./tester.db")
data = {'date': ['20210210', '20210209'], 'value': [15, 17]}
df_add = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value'], index=data['date'])
df_add.to_sql('placeA', con, if_exists='replace')
con.close()

# Update DB using index
con = sqlite3.connect("./tester.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE placeA SET value = ? WHERE index = ?", (232, "20210210"))
con.commit()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM placeA")
f = cur.fetchall()
print(f)
```

Comment: I guess it might be a solution to change index column's name using "cur.execute("ALTER TABLE placeA RENAME COLUMN 'index' to date")" but I'm still not sure why 'index' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it doesn't work properly if the column named 'index' in sql file.

So I figured it out by renaming 'index' column to 'date'.

but I need to keep the column name 'index' so I changed it again after..

```
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE placeA RENAME COLUMN 'index' to date")
...
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE placeA RENAME COLUMN date to 'index'")
```